# JavaFX: why scrollpane is including a splitpane?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to understand how widgets in JavaFX work, and given the following FXML I don't get why a `ScrollPane`is putting a split in after the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <top>
        <Pane prefHeight="195.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Group>
                    <children>
                        <Label layoutX="58.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Testlabel "/>
                    </children>
                </Group>
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </top>
    <center>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <content>
                <ListView/>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <ToolBar layoutX="-86.0" layoutY="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <items>

            </items>
        </ToolBar>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

I just want to have a `ListView` with a possiblity to scroll if the list is too long. Using JavaFX included in the latest JDK 8 (1.8.0_05) on Linux Mint.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need a ScrollPane to scroll a ListView. A ListView already provides this funtionality.

Comment: There is no [SplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) added.

Answer (score -1):

Putting  `minWidth="600"` as an attribute of `ListView` fixes the problem:

```
    <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <ListView minWidth="600"/>
    </ScrollPane>
```

But I must admit it is utterly unintuitive. JavaFX should figure by itself out what the preferred width should be. Smells like Swing people developing JavaFX.